# How can I relocate a resources directory?

Tags: android-studio, gradle

I want to move my resources directory form `./src/main/res` to `./res` in the interests of porting an app from Eclipse to Android Studio

I've added these lines to my build.gradle file:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        resources {
            srcDirs = ["./res"]
        }
    }
}
```

and Android Studio *seems* to recognize this after syncing my gradle files, but not really. When I open an xml file from res/layout it's clearly not recognized as a layout file, and I get the error message `http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android "URI is not registered (Settings | Languages & Frameworks | Schemas and DTDs)"`

Is there a way to re-arrange my source files, or is `sourceSets.main.resources.srcDirs` a lie?

---

Adding on: I did try using `res` instead of `resources`. This was the result:

```
Build file '/Users/falk/Android/Foo/fooapp/build.gradle' line: 33

A problem occurred evaluating project ':fooapp'.
> No signature of method: build_ag5e2qc90oc7bck5pxaqmbzuf.sourceSets() is applicable for argument types: (build_ag5e2qc90oc7bck5pxaqmbzuf$_run_closure2) values: [build_ag5e2qc90oc7bck5pxaqmbzuf$_run_closure2@4536888e]

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating project ':fooapp'.
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:93)
    ...
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: build_ag5e2qc90oc7bck5pxaqmbzuf.sourceSets() is applicable for argument types: (build_ag5e2qc90oc7bck5pxaqmbzuf$_run_closure2) values: [build_ag5e2qc90oc7bck5pxaqmbzuf$_run_closure2@4536888e]
    at build_ag5e2qc90oc7bck5pxaqmbzuf.run(/Users/falk/Android/Foo/fooapp/build.gradle:33)
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:91)
    ... 140 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `res` instead of `resources`

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        res {
            srcDirs = ["./res"]
        }
    }
}
```

```
// com.android.build.api.dsl.AndroidSourceSet
/** The Java-style resources for this source-set */
val resources: AndroidSourceDirectorySet

/** The Android Resources directory for this source-set. */
val res: AndroidSourceDirectorySet
```

Comment: That was one of the first things I tried. The error was too complicated to put into a comment; see my edit.

Comment: I created a new Project using AS with AGP 7.1.0-beta05, applied above code snippet, did not see any errors. I also can not make sure what happened after you changed to `res` (the missing signature error), may be you need to create a MVCE on somewhere to make it more clear. https://s3.bmp.ovh/imgs/2021/12/4c7eefca536e002f.png

Comment: I think I've found the issue. I was creating my `sourceSets` directive at the top level, but for Android it needs to be inside the `android` directive. I'm testing that theory now.

Comment: @EdwardFalk That's true, put it into `android{}`please.

Comment: Yep, that was it. Change `resources` to `res` and move it inside the `android` directive.